# ApolloClient readFragment returns empty object

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

Accordingly to [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/#readfragment) this is all it takes to query something from apollo cache but it isn't working and the `console.log()` is showing an empty object. The first image show that I have the entity cached.

- change `optimistic` to false doesn't change the result
- change the id to "141" change the return from empty object to 'null'
- `import gql from "graphql-tag";`
- `"apollo-client": "^2.6.8",`
- `"graphql-tag": "^2.10.0",`

```
onClick: p => {
  const readFragment = apolloClient.readFragment({
    id: 141,
    fragment: gql`
      fragment myMarca on Marca {
        id
      }
    `,
    optimistic: true,
  });
  console.log(readFragment);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was passing `id: 141`. The right way is `Marca:141`. Found it from [this answer](https://spectrum.chat/apollo/apollo-client/why-doesnt-client-readfragment-work~f405dc79-57dc-412f-b0d2-7262f4bb9ab5?m=MTU4OTQ1NjE0MDYxNg==) inside Apollo Spectrum Community.